# Polygon selectable point event doesn't fire for innerCoords points

Tags: google-maps

Below I have a google map containing a [polygon with a hole in it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole).

I have the following event listeners:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', getPolygonCoords(myPolygon))
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPath(), 'set_at', getPolygonCoords(myPolygon))
```

For some reason when I move any of the `innerCoords`, none of the events fire.

[image]

How can I access an event that fires when the innerCoords are moved?

```
const getPolygonCoords = (myPolygon) => () => {
  var len = myPolygon.getPath().getLength()
  let points = []
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let point = myPolygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(5).split(',')
    let lat = parseFloat(point[0])
    let lng = parseFloat(point[1])  
    points.push({lat, lng})
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(points))
  this.props.onChange(points)
}
```

Comment: What is `getPolygonCoords`? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It's simply a callback that fires when the event is triggered. I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: It probably is wrong, unless it returns a function.

Comment: `const getPolygonCoords = (myPolygon) => () =>       console.log(JSON.stringify(points))`
It does

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the listeners to all the paths, not just the first.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g47bcd8L/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < myPolygon.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPaths().getAt(i), 'insert_at', getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPaths().getAt(i), 'set_at', getPolygonCoords);
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example creates a triangular polygon with a hole in it.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 24.886,
      lng: -70.268
    },
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's  outer path.
  var outerCoords = [{
    lat: 25.774,
    lng: -80.190
  }, {
    lat: 18.466,
    lng: -66.118
  }, {
    lat: 32.321,
    lng: -64.757
  }];

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's inner path.
  // Note that the points forming the inner path are wound in the
  // opposite direction to those in the outer path, to form the hole.
  var innerCoords = [{
    lat: 28.745,
    lng: -70.579
  }, {
    lat: 29.570,
    lng: -67.514
  }, {
    lat: 27.339,
    lng: -66.668
  }];

  // Construct the polygon, including both paths.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [outerCoords, innerCoords],
    strokeColor: '#FFC107',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FFC107',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  bermudaTriangle.setEditable(true);
  for (var i = 0; i < bermudaTriangle.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPaths().getAt(i), 'insert_at', getPolygonCoords);
    google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPaths().getAt(i), 'set_at', getPolygonCoords);
  }

}

function getPolygonCoords() {
  console.log("getPolygonCoords");
  for (var i = 0; i < this.getLength(); i++) {
    console.log(this.getAt(i).toUrlValue(6));
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason `getPolygonCoords` is only getting one point at a time. I need an array of all the `outerPoints`, and `innerPoints` from within the handler. Thoughts?

Comment: You have the same problem in your getPolygonCoords function, you are only processing the first path.